# How do you post a form field collection to a Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have form such as this:

```
<form method="post" action="/create">

    <input type="text" name="title.0" value="Curious George" />
    <input type="text" name="author.0" value="H.A. Rey" />
    <input type="text" name="date.0" value="2/23/1973" />

    <input type="text" name="title.1" value="Code Complete" />
    <input type="text" name="author.1" value="Steve McConnell" />
    <input type="text" name="date.1" value="6/9/2004" />

    <input type="text" name="title.2" value="The Two Towers" />
    <input type="text" name="author.2" value="JRR Tolkien" />
    <input type="text" name="date.2" value="6/1/2005" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How do I parse this from a Spring MVC 3.0 controller?

Answer (score 9):

The `name` attribute need not be unique. So:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="title" value="Code Complete" />
<input type="text" name="title" value="The Two Towers" />
```

And then

```
@RequestMapping("/create")
public void create(
    @RequestParam("title") List<String> titles, 
    @RequestParam("author") List<String> authors, ..) {..}
```

The order of the elements should be preserved, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by '=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by '&'.

Answer (score 4):

If you can change the view, ideally you'd do this with some kind of list.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="books[0].title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="books[0].author" value="H.A. Rey" />
<input type="text" name="books[0].date" value="2/23/1973" />
```

you would have a **Book** class containing your 3 elements.
and a containing class which contains a list of books **BookContainer**

```
public class BookContainer {
  private List <Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

  public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
  }

  public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
  }
}
```

Now in your controller, you'd have a `@ModelAttribute` method which returns the Containing class to to bind to:

```
@ModelAttribute("container")
public BookContainer getBookContainer() {
  return new BookContainer;
}
```

finally you'd have a @ModelAttribute parameter to your request mapping method:

```
@RequestMapping
public void handlePost(@ModelAttribute("container") BookContainer container) {

}
```

spring will automatically add as many 'Book's to your list as you need.

Comment: I tried for quite a while today to get this idea to work with no luck.  I even removed the bulk of my code and put yours in with no dice.  Any suggestions or pointers on making this actually work?

Comment: What version of spring MVC are you using? I recall that there was a bug in 3.0.0 that the [] didn't work. I am currently using 3.0.5 - I will also give this a bit of a test a bit later to check that I didn't miss anything.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the major reason it didn't work was that it seems you can't bind directly back to a List, but it works fine if your list is contained within another class.

Comment: Thanks kieron.  I'm on 3.0.5 also.  I'll have a look at this tonight and see if I can make it work.  It would be great since it's cleaner than my answer of just getting the WebRequest.

Comment: Finally, now your ModelAttribute is "container" but in your requestmapping you are still referencing "books"  Is that what you intended?  Also, would the names of the inputs elements need to change to container.books[0].title etc. or not?

Comment: both of the model attributes need to match (which I have fixed). The inputs are one level lower - essentially the form maps to the container (but you don't need to do anything special to say this)

Comment: Got this working fine.  Thanks for the help and clarification.  I didn't actually have to use the @ModelAttribute at all.  Wish I could up-vote you more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Could your controller request mapping simply take a spring [WebRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html) as the parameter and then do something like:

```
Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
int i = 0;
while ( true ) {
    String title = params.get( "title" + .i );
    if ( title != null ) {
        // get the rest and create your Book object or whatever
        i += 1;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```